# Focus sunlight into a line and not just a point with lenses

Tags: visible-light, refraction, lenses

Using a magnifying lens with the sun as the source, one can focus the light in a single point.
Is it possible to use just lenses, or any number of transparent materials of any particular shapes, to focus sunlight into a line and not just a point, and turning it into what I think is called a "focused beam of light"?
Is it possible to do with just transparent materials?

Comment: A cylindrical lens will focus sunlight into a "line of light", but that is not the same as a beam. There are, however, ways of making a nearly ideal and monochromatic beam out of sunlight: we use a solar panel to generate electricity and then power a laser with that electricity. The process is lossy, but not nearly as lossy as attempts would be to do this directly with passive optical mechanisms like lenses. The reasons for that are ultimately thermodynamical in nature.

Comment: A focused beam is one with the rays converging to a focal point or maybe focal area. What you describe for the first case is already a focused beam.

Comment: @FlatterMann I don't mind if the process is lossy as long as the result is a line of focused sunlight. Is the process you're talking about doable with only transparent materials?

Comment: @nasu I did a quick search. Is the proper term "parallel light" then? Or "Collimated beam"?

Comment: Transparent materials are not lossy be definition. So, no, the process is not possible "merely" with transparent materials.

Comment: Lasers produce collimated beans using an optical cavity. This is two mirrors facing each other. One is slightly transparent so some of the light can get out. The details get complicated. No beam can ever be perfectly collimated, but they can be so close it is hard to tell the difference. You can read about such beans here. [Gaussian Beams](https://www.rp-photonics.com/gaussian_beams.html)

Comment: @Wajih Aziza Proper term for what? The sun rays are already parallel.